# Different ways to display the value of a selected dropdown option in laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel

I am currently working with this site wherein if you are not a local from that country, multiple input fields will be disabled. So, what I am trying to do is to display the selected option from a dropdown that has been queried from a database table. ill provide the code for it and some pictures for you to better understand it.

Here is the **Controller**:

```
    public function get_citizenship()
    {

        $citizenships = CitizenshipModel::orderBy('citizens')->get();
        $opt="<option selected value''>Select Citizenship</option>";
        foreach($citizenships as $citizenship)
        {
            if($citizenship -> id > 0)
            $opt.="<option value={$citizenship->id}>{$citizenship->citizens}</option>";
        }
        return $opt;
    }

    

    public function citizenship(){
        $data = UserModel::where('seq_id','=',Session::get('loginId'))->first();
        $data['displayCitizenship']=$this->get_citizenship();
        $data['displayProvince']=$this->get_province();
        $data['displayMunicipality']=$this->get_municipality();
        return view ("countries", $data);
    }
```

And here is the **Blade** file. I have two types of select. one is locally where i coded the value, and the other one is the one i queried from a database table.

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-4">
 <div class="form-group row">
   <label for="step1_gender" class="col-sm-3 text-right control-label col-form-label">Gender</label>
     <div class="col-sm-9">
      <select class="form-control" type="date" id='step1_gender' >
        <option>Select Gender</option>
        <option value="male" >Male</option>
        <option value="female" >Female</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



<div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-4">
 <div class="form-group row">
  <label for="step1_citizenship" class="col-sm-3 text-right control-label col-form-label">Citizenship</label>
   <div class="col-sm-9">
    <select class="form-control" type="text" required="" placeholder="Last Name" id='step1_citizenship'  >
     {!! $displayCitizenship !!}
    </select>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

[This is the one i chose and inserted in my users info table. but whenever i refresh the page, it returns to **Select Citizenship** option. how can i show the selected option for each logged in user?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ZOnP.png)

I tried googling and looking for youtube vids but i can't find the nearest answer.

Comment: So you what you want is to fill the form with the currently logged in user data ?

Comment: Yes, displaying the user's selected option whenever he returns to the page

Comment: can you explain the process ?

Comment: So you want the option of "Citizenship" to be selected based on the user data?

Comment: yes based on the users data in the database

Comment: Here is the process:

A user will be redirected to a page after logging in, in this page, he/she will answer a form about his/her nationality. after getting the users data, i want to display it in the input field so whenever he/she returns, it will be displayed. also, how can i keep the input fields disabled if he or she is not a local based on citizenship?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the option of citizenship to be selected based on the current user's data (assuming you `$this->get_citizenship()` retrieves the correct data from the current user), you can simply add a turnery condition for the selected option.

```
$current_citizen = $this->get_citizenship();

foreach($citizenships as $citizenship)
{
    if($citizenship -> id > 0) {
        $selected = $citizenship->citizens == $current_citizen ? 'selected' : '';
        $opt.="<option value={$citizenship->id} ${selected}>{$citizenship->citizens}</option>";
    }
}
```

Comment: im getting this error PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) and i cant load the page

Comment: This is a very simple change that should not take that much memory let alone exhaust the entire memory size. The issue might be elsewhere.

Comment: if($citizenship -> id > 0) this might be the problem

Comment: i have 243 rows in my country table, i think its trying to get all the rows

Comment: This might be because we called $this->get_citizenship() function in each iteration. I updated the answer and moved it outside the foreach loop. Try this one and see if it helps.

Comment: PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 65536 bytes) in C:\xampp\htdocs\com-applicant\vendor\psr\log\src\LogLevel.php on line 8.

Comment: Failed to load response data: No resource with given identifier found

Comment: What does $this->get_citizenship() function returns?

Comment: it returns all listed countries from the table which have 243 listed options. thats a pretty huge data

Comment: I assumed it simply returns the citizenship of the current user. I guess you need to find the way to pass the users citizenship to your function to compare it in your foreach loop and select the match.

Comment: can you help me in that query?